# Proving $1/x$ is uniformly continuous on $[1/2,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

We wish to prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ defined on $[1/2,1]$ is uniformly continuous.

Scratch work:
Take $x,y \in [1/2,1]$, $|f(y)-f(x)|=|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}|=|\frac{y-x}{xy}|$

At most $x=1,y=1$ so at most $|xy|=1$. Then $$\frac{|y-x|}{|xy|}\le|y-x|<\delta$$
So if we choose $\delta = \varepsilon$ our proof will be complete.

Proof:
$\varepsilon>0 $ is given, choose $\delta = \varepsilon$,
$x,y\in[1/2,1]$ satisfying $|y-x|<\delta$ are given.

$|f(y)-f(x)|=|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}|=|\frac{y-x}{xy}|\le|y-x| <\delta=\varepsilon$.

The proof is complete.

Is this all correct?

Comment: Are you aware of [Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem) ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I am, however this had to be done by definition.

Comment: Consider $\epsilon=\frac{2}{3}, x=1, y=\frac{1}{2}$ as a counterexample to your proof, can you see what you did wrong?

Comment: @MorA. Yes, I should have minimised $|xy|$ so that $|y-x|$ was maximal. Thank you.

Comment: Notice that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 4|x-y|$ for all $1/2\leq x,y\leq1$.